# Microsoft Excel if statement or vlookup

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

### Heading

hello guys im trying to get a formula to do a task for me
i have 2 excel workbooks opened
both of them have people names and beside names there is ID 
but the numbers are different in the 2 workbooks 
so what im doing now is copying every name and go to the other sheet and see if is it exist there i take the number beside and i go back to the first sheet i took the name from it and and i new column i add the number
if you didn't get that for my bad English maybe this will make it easier

If a name in sheet 1 column 2 =equal= a name sheet 2 column 2 then get the number beside the name in the sheet 2 if not then "NA"

thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a list of names in the A Column and a list of ID's in the B Column plus a list of names on a different sheet and you want to copy the ID's from Column B on Sheet 1 to Column B on Sheet 2 or have "N/A" where they done exist.

Assuming this is correct, the easiest way is via a `VLOOKUP()` I made the below example to show you how this would work:

Picture one is your METADATA, this is data where you have the name and ID of each of your people:

[image: One]

Picture two is where you have your results:

[image: Two]

In `Cell B2` on `Sheet 2` you have the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2;Sheet1!A:B;2;FALSE)
```

Drag this formula down to all cells you need to ID number for in `Sheet 2`

You will need to replace cell references as needed.

Comment: thanks but i have tried this not working i don't know what is the reason
my problem is both workbooks have same names but different  id's
i used vlookup but only working when i get text not the id beside the name

Comment: Can you supply actual data? Maybe take a screenshot of the data in both tables?

Comment: i can't upload any of this data or screenshot its confidential but i give you example for a formula that worked but its getting the names not the id's
=VLOOKUP(C:C,'[Details.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$B,1,FALSE)

Comment: Change some of the data. If the name is "Yousef Farra" and ID is "XLP9021" then change it to name "YF" and ID "1234", the important thing is seeing what you are working with. Regarding your formula, I am surprised it works at all, the first argument (C:C) needs to be a single value, you are looking up an entire range, try changing to C1, C2 ect. Your second value needs to be a table, currently it is only a column....

Comment: Try changing to "=VLOOKUP(C1,'[Details.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$C,1,FALSE)" where the name you are looking up is in cell C1.